Moduli of parabolic bundles of rank two on projective line
Corresponding to a weight $(1/2,1/2,...,1/2)$ at $2g+2$ points,one has a moduli space $M^{par}(2)$ of parabolic rank two bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$ with trivial determinant.
It is constructed as a GIT quotient $(\mathbb{P}^1)^{2g+2}//PGL(2)$. the moduli space $\overline{M_{0,n}}$ is also a GIT quotient $(\mathbb{P}^1)^{2g+2}//PGL(2)$.
Is there a birational morphism between these two moduli spaces, equivariant for the automorphism groups.

Did you check Kapranov's 1993 paper? From what i remember, he gives you this and much more.

thanks, the paper gives explicit resolutions.
